# How to compute/measure inference time of a Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have 2 TF models that I wanted to compare in terms of how fast they can predict. I'm aware that TF models have `evaluate` method that outputs ms per step inference. However, is there a way to have higher precision than this? If so, what's the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import time
start_time=time.time()
model.predict( etc.......
end_time=time.time()
duration= end_time-start_time
hours = tr_duration // 3600
minutes = (tr_duration - (hours * 3600)) // 60
seconds = tr_duration - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))
msg = f'training elapsed time was {str(hours)} hours, {minutes:4.1f} minutes, {seconds:4.2f} seconds)_
print (msg) # print out training duration time
```

Comment: This is inaccurate, especially if you are using gpu. https://deci.ai/blog/measure-inference-time-deep-neural-networks/